# query data (rows) on another table with same id and removing the result with only one data

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have example of my SELECT query returning data but I want to remove or exclude the result with only 1 data return.

```
SELECT m.roverbook,
       m.Sequence,
       m.AccountNumber,
       m.Name,
       c.duedate,
       c.amount as Bill
FROM unpaidbills c
LEFT JOIN master m ON (m.id = c.uid)
WHERE m.roverbook = '010101'
  AND c.duedate < '2017-01-10'
ORDER BY m.Sequence
```

RESULT SAMPLE

```
roverbook   Sequence    AccountNumber   Name    duedate Bill
10101   1001    1010010 CHUA, SOLIDAD   1/5/2003    514.41
10101   1001    1010010 CHUA, SOLIDAD   2/5/2003    614.97
10101   1001    1010010 CHUA, SOLIDAD   6/5/2003    264.58
10101   1002    1010040 CRUZ, BENITO    10/5/2001   1156.26
10101   1002    1010040 CRUZ, BENITO    11/5/2001   1775.42
10101   1003    1010051 SERRANO, NOMER  10/5/2001   633.41
10101   1004    1010221 C H A P E L 11/7/2014   128.41
```

I want to remove the result with only one Bill

Comment: please post an example too

Comment: please show some data of your table and query output in tabular format

Comment: which data do you want?

Comment: can you elaborate your condition? I mean which one data you want and what else should remove?

Comment: Edited.

I want to remove the row with only one bill. Or example in the result i want to remove SERRANO, NOMER and C H A P E L because they only have one bill

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will return records with multiple bills only based on sequence:

```
SELECT m.roverbook,
       m.Sequence,
       m.AccountNumber,
       m.Name,
       c.duedate,
       c.amount
FROM unpaidbills c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM master WHERE sequence IN (select m1.sequence from master m1 group by m1.roverbook, m1.sequence having count(m1.sequence) > 1)) m ON (m.id = c.uid)
WHERE m.roverbook = '010101'
  AND c.duedate < '2017-01-10'
ORDER BY m.Sequence
```

Comment: what is the purpose of m1?

Comment: Nothing special but good to have alias when you are using same tables multiple time or joining the multiple tables, I have added alias to join the table but after I got this idea of using sub query. It will exclude the sequence 1003 and 1004 from your given sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.roverbook,
   m.Sequence,
   m.AccountNumber,
   m.Name,
   c.duedate,
   c.amount as Bill
FROM unpaidbills c
LEFT JOIN master m ON (m.id = c.uid)
Left join
(
   SELECT 
   m.id,
   count(c.uid) as BillCount
   FROM unpaidbills c
   LEFT JOIN master m ON (m.id = c.uid)
   WHERE m.roverbook = '010101'
   AND c.duedate < '2017-01-10'
   group by m.id
   having count(c.uid)>1
 ) MorethanoneBill
 on(m.id = MorethanoneBill.id)
 WHERE m.roverbook = '010101'
 AND c.duedate < '2017-01-10'
 ORDER BY m.Sequence
```